# Is there a way to read the barcode from a barcode scanner device?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, barcode, barcode-scanner

If I open a Notepad and read a barcode from barcode scanner device and keep the focus on notepad it writes the Barcode on Notepad window. I just want the same output in my **C# program**, for that I have created a `textbox` and keep the focus on my textbox and the **output is what I wanted**. Now if the case is I **dont** have a `textbox` how should assign same string to some of my **variable**. I have done the research but got a lot of libraries which are reading it from images or some dlls for it. I am sure there is some easy way out for this.

Thanks for the help in advance

Comment: I think the barcode scanners just send keystrokes to your application. Can you catch this at the form level (need to set the KeyPreview to true to get the keystrokes sent to the form)

Comment: @LeeWillis - Is this the right [link](http://www.codeproject.com/script/Articles/ViewDownloads.aspx?aid=296533) to follow

Comment: You'd have to look at that link and decide whether that works for you. The basic principle is as I described.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Set the forms KeyPreview event to true. Then wire up a handler for the Form KeyUp event and handle the keystrokes there. The data the scanner sends just looks like you pressing the keyboard to Windows so it will pass on the events to your application.

Comment: Good, but there is something remaining...
How to limit the `KeyUp` event for the barcode scanner only? I mean that I want my C# app to only accept input from the barcode scanner and if the user hit some key from the keyboard the app ignores it..

Comment: This is a 4 1/2 year old answer.... the scanner I worked on years ago let you configure pre / post append text to the scanner text, so you could look for these and filter out scanner or keyboard hits. eg keyboard would send 1234, scanner would send !!1234!!.

Comment: Wills
Thanks for replying, please can you help me about this nowadays? I mean do new barcode scanners function this way now? and do you have any good barcode emulator on windows good fits with C#?

Comment: Sorry but I haven't done anything with barcodes for years. I don't suppose scanners have changed much but I think it's really down to the particular scanner you are working with.

Answer (score 1):

One of my coworkers recently worked with a barcode scanner (a Motorola) and I helped him on that project.

Unfortunately, every barcode scanner has a different implementation for reading barcodes (although the general mechanics are usually similar). You will have to download the SDK for your barcode scanner device. Check the website of the manufacturer on how to install it.

Generally, you'll have to add a reference to their DLL, then put a handler on their OnRead event (or whatever they call it). that usually has a special object as an event argument, that contains the data the reader sends.

I know I'm really vague here, but there's not much I can say without knowing the exact brand and model of the scanner. You'll have to do some research yourself on this matter.

Comment: I have Honeywell. But that is not what my question is. I am trying to understand that when a textbox get the value and notepad can get the value why i cant get the same easily why should i use DLLs for it. But +1 for appreciating your effort

Comment: @MohitShrivastava You can simply scan to enter it in notepad or a textbox because the scanner sends the code in a way that can be read by those programs. In essence, Windows intercepts the call itself (or a program installed in Windows) and knows what to do with it. However, your C# program does not, by default, know what to do with the scanner information. In fact, if you don't explicitly tell it to bind to the scanner Read function, your C# program will just ignore it, just like Notepad will by default ignore network traffic because it's irrelevant.

Comment: You can scan into notepad (or your textbox) because the scanner just sends keyboard key strokes. You have proven this by scanning into a textbox with nothing more than setting the focus. To Windows it looks like you just typed them in on the keyboard so they are sent to your application as such. I have used a barcode scanner in a browser based app that required no external libraries - just the ability to handle keystroke events. You can check this by using the KeyPreview method I mentioned above.